# read property file from a dependent project with maven

Tags: properties, maven, dependencies

I have an issue when reading properties from a dependent project.

I have a core project, and my application has a dependency on it.

under classpath of core, it has file `core.properties`.

and my application need to read this property file, but it couldn't.  It requires the `core.properties` in my classpath of my application, instead of core.

Is there an solution for that? One solution in my mind is that when I build my `application.war`, can I explictly declare that I want the core dependency be exploded?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "read this property file"?

Since it will be on the classpath it should be accessible with `getClass().getResourceAsStream()`.

If you really need it as a file, you can use the Dependency plugin's `unpack-dependencies` goal to unpack particular files as part of the build process.

Comment: I mean that the property file I want to read is in a jar file, and it's used as a dependency in another module.  And when I try to read the properties in my module, it couldn't find it because that properties file is in the depenedency jar file. not on the classpath of my module.

Am I explaining clearly? Sorry for my bad english :) and does anyone has a good solution?

I will have a look into unpack dependencies also.