# Add properties file from a project dependency to project classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, classpath

I have two maven projects: project (A) and another project (B) that is a dependency of A. B contains a properties file that I wish to access in one of A's controllers. Is there a way to add B's properties file to A's classpath so that I can inject it into A's controller?

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468756/read-property-file-from-a-dependent-project-with-maven) but I'm not sure if the scope of my question is covered by it.

**UPDATE:**
Using the @Value annotation in A's controller, the project returns a 500 error code and a FileNotFoundException.

Comment: If B is a dependency of A, shouldn't it be in its classpath already?

Comment: Yes, and I'm using the @Value annotation to try and read it, but I get a filenotfoundexception.

Comment: I'd suggest posting some code and package hierarchy.